# ArcPy Traceback (most recent call last): error

Tags: python, arcpy, traceback

I used Model Builder to convert feature classes within a geodatabase into shapefiles into a preexisting folder.  It ran successfully.  However, when i exported the Model into a Python Script and ran it in Python, I get an error saying:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mark.Novicio\Desktop\New folder\FSA_Counties_delivered_by_GISO\Updated_Iterators.py", line 13, in 
    arcpy.ImportToolbox("Model Functions")

The python script is attached in the image:

[image]

Comment: Please post the actual code. It's too awkward trying to read the code from an image especially as people can't run it that way.

Comment: Is there more to the error message? This looks like just the top of the traceback.

Answer (score 2):

ArcPy code exported from ModelBuilder often needs a lot of tweaking, although it can be a moderately useful starting point.

[`IterateFeatureClasses_mb` is the python-code of a ModelBuilder only tool.](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Classes/00400000000r000000/)

> This tool is intended for use in ModelBuilder and not in Python scripting.

Since you want to use Python instead, you need to use a normal iterator (generally, a `for` loop running through a list of feature classes). You can automatically [build the list with arcpy.ListFeatureClasses](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000018000000), and then just loop:

```
# set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = Test_gdb

# get a list of feature classes in arcpy.env.workspace
listFC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# iterate
for fc in listFC:
    #
    # code to do to fc
    #
```

If you're only planning to use that list of feature classes once, call `ListFeatureClasses` in the `for` loop:

```
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
```

In either case, you'll need to [look at `FeatureClassToFeatureClass` for outputting a shapefile](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000020000000) once you get your loop working :)